# Why is no option in my layer-control activated?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bing-maps

my map is generated by this code (edited after advice):

```
var BING_KEY = "My Bing Maps Key";
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

function show_karte(div_id, mittelpunkt, zoom, overlay, typ){
var bingLayer = L.tileLayer.bing({bingMapsKey: BING_KEY, maxZoom: 20,   imagerySet: 'Aerial', attribution: '&copy; 2019 Microsoft Corporation, Earthstar Geographics SIO'});
var bingLabelLayer = L.tileLayer.bing({bingMapsKey: BING_KEY, maxZoom: 20, imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels', attribution: '&copy; 2019 Microsoft Corporation, Earthstar Geographics SIO'});
var osmLayer = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 20, attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'});
var mittelpunkt = [mittelpunkt[1], mittelpunkt[0]]
var aktuellerLayer;
switch (typ) {
   case 'A' : aktuellerLayer = bingLayer; break;
   case 'L' : aktuellerLayer = bingLabelLayer;  break;
   case 'R' : aktuellerLayer = osmLayer;
   };
var map = L.map(div_id,{fullscreenControl: true, layers: [aktuellerLayer]}).setView(mittelpunkt, zoom);
var overlayLayers = null; 
var baseLayers = {"Stra&szlig;enkarte": osmLayer, "Luftbild mit Stra&szlig;ennamen": bingLabelLayer,"Luftbild": bingLayer}; 
var controls = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayLayers).addTo(map);

$.ajax(overlay).done(function(data) {
var data = JSON.parse(data);
L.geoJson(data, 
        {
        });
  });
};
```

"show_karte" is called on a webiste three times every time with another div-id and first function-parameter with:

```
<div class="bild_rechts" id="map" style="width:450px; height: 700px;">
    <script  type="text/javascript"> show_karte("map",[6.026173,50.816022],13,"neueFlaechen.geojson","L"); </script>
</div>

<div id="map1" style="width:450px; height: 700px;">
    <script  type="text/javascript"> show_karte("map1",[6.10428,50.76079],11,"konzentrationsflaechen.geojson","A"); </script>
</div>

<div id="map2" style="width:795px; height:1000px">  
    <script  type="text/javascript">show_karte("map2",[6.10428,50.76079],12,"moeglicheFlaechen.geojson","R"); </script>
</div>
```

In all three cases I see the map control, but ONLY on the third map, an option is activated. Can someone tell the error? - Thanks for reading the code!

Gruss, wonk

Comment: How do the other two calls to `show_karte()`  look like?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use your layers on different maps simultaneously. Only the last one will retain the layer.

You simply need to duplicate your layers for each map, e.g. by moving their creation code within your show_carte function.

Comment: Then please _edit_ your question (instead of using an "answer") and provide an MCVE.